# Алгоритм для поиска максимальной стоимости прохода по графу с заданным количеством замен

Tags: c#, c++, python, алгоритм

Есть ненаправленный взвешенный граф. А также, заданное количество возможных изменений веса рёбер графа - **K** и стоимость на которую можно заменить вес ребра - **M**.

Задача заключается в том, чтобы посчитать какой максимальной стоимости прохода от самой первой вершины до всех остальных можно добиться с помощью фиксированного количества замен **K** на стоимость **M**. И найти минимальное количество замен для достижения такого результата со номерами всех измененный ребер.

К примеру, есть граф (в программу он поступает в виде ребер, каждая строка новое ребро. Самая первая содержит три числа **N** - количество вершин, **K** и **M**):

```
7 1 2
1 2 3
1 3 2
1 4 4
1 5 1
6 5 15
7 5 10
```

[image: граф]

Для него ответом будет являться:

- максимальная стоимость проезда от 1 до всех остальных - **40**
- количество необходимых замен - **1**
- номера ребер на которых нужна заменить веса

Здесь, выгодно поменять вес ребра из 1-ой вершины в 5-ую. Максимальная стоимость высчитывается так: 3+2+4+2+(15+2)+(10+2)=40

Я пробовал решать так:
с помощью обхода графа в глубину мы находим количество дочерних вершин каждой вершины, а после брать из них вершину с самым большим количеством дочерних. Но на частных случаях такой подход не работает.

Подскажите, способы для решения задачи.

Comment: 1. По поводу обхода графа, мне всегда казалось что только два способа - в ширину и в глубину. (можно ещё то же с ограничением по ширине/глубине, тут думаю неприемлемо)  2. Если вы решаете задачу 1 - макс стоимость проезда - зачем вы выбираете макс-кво-вершин? Расчитывайте по-ходу сразу стоимость проезда, заносите её в max, расчётную величину сбрасывайте перед следущим проходом.

Comment: Т.е. всё верно, самый длинный (макс вершин) путь - не всегда самый дорогой.